# Explore transaction from truffle test file

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I have create this test:

```
const { expectEvent } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');

contract('MyContract', function (accounts) {
    const [owner] = accounts;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.myContract = await MyContract.new({from: owner});
    });

    describe('construction', function () {
        let txHash = this.myContract.transactionHash

    });
});
```

txHash contains the hash of the deployment transaction.
How can i access to all transaction fields (especially "from" field)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the transaction hash, you can do this:

You can specify the network you want to debug on with the `--network` option:

```
$ truffle debug [<transaction hash>] --network <network>
```

Reference from: [debugging-your-contracts](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/debugging-your-contracts#command)

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want to do that in javascript...